Sympy 3d plot with Relu is possible?
Is it impossible to plot the Relu function 3d using sympy? The professor said it would be an error, but I don't know what you mean. Please help me... I don't know why. What kind of error is it? Is it because I have to use matplotlib...?
Using sympy, how to know where the error occurs, and how to 3dplot the Relu function in other ways.

Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
